# What is the proper (or preferred way) to configure a static factory class?

Tags: programming-practices, patterns-and-practices, factory, static, factory-pattern

First SE stack,

I am working on a large chunk of old Java code and am finding tons of duplication and inconsistently configured/created objects because of different authors, skill levels, etc.

I have implemented a few static factory patterns and am having a debate as how to make the factory configurable.

EDIT: per comment suggestions,

Option A:

```
public final class TacoFactory {

    private static int defaultCheese = 0;

    private TacoFactory() {}

    public static Taco createTaco(int cheese) {}

    public static Taco createDefaultTaco() { createTaco(defaultCheese); }

    public static synchronized void configure(int cheese) { 
        this.defaultCheese = cheese; 
    }
}
```

Option B:

```
public final class TacoFactory {

    public static int defaultCheese = 0;

    private TacoFactory() {}

    public static Taco createTaco(int cheese) {}

    public static Taco createDefaultTaco() { createTaco(defaultCheese); }
}
```

Option C: 
Some elite way/pattern that google-fu has yet to give me. If there is some good documentation on this pattern, please share. :)

Option D: Doesn't matter and/or isn't specified.

Option E: Builder Pattern, although I voiced my concerns as to why I don't think this fits my use case on the answer that suggest it below.

```
class Taco {
    private final int cheese;
    private final int beef;

    Taco(int cheese, int beef) {
        this.cheese = cheese;
        this.beef = beef;
    }
}

class TacoBuilder {
    private int cheese = 0; 

    TacoBuilder setCheese(int cheese) {
        this.cheese = cheese;
        return this;
    }

    TacoBuilder setBeef(int beef) {
        this.beef = beef;
        return this;
    }

    Taco build() {
        return new Taco(a, b);
    }
}

Foo foo = new FooBuilder().setA("a").build();
```

Comment: what is your motivation for having "setDefaultCheese" in option A?

Comment: Underlying reason is that as code is being rewritten, I am trying to be flexible to the current configuration management.

Currently, system is pulling configuration from xml file on a per object creation basis (terrible for this system in my opinion). The plan is to move it to one time configuration read to some config object and configuring objects on construction from the configuration that will now be in memory. I have no control over that plan and who knows, it could change again, so my thinking is being able to configure defaultCheese might be redundant but more flexible in the end.

Comment: tldr; making the default configurable is more flexible in the long run and hopefully makes the code completely reusable.

Comment: Which option most effectively satisfies your specific software requirements?

Comment: Making defaultCheese mutable will definitely increase the possibilities for error.

Comment: is this java, C#, or some weird language that has no return keyword?

Comment: To complete @FrankHileman you may run in issues with concurrency, you have to be sure youre setter is only called at application startup, or you need to synchronise all your method.

Comment: @CandiedOrange its java, as stated in the question. that was almost funny :)

Comment: @FrankHileman I want to make the factory configurable to keep it flexible in the long run. a single synchronized configure method?

Comment: @Walfrat good feedback, thank you. i couldn't tag you in the above^

Comment: You can only tag one people per comment, so it's normal.

Comment: @Walfrat yeah, i was meaning the question is directed to you as well. I ran some tests and hit the concurrency issues you were talking about. i fixed those with a static synchronized method to reconfigure the factory. i also created some value checking for the "defaultCheese" based on Frank's comment to prevent illegal values or improper configurations.

Comment: @finleyarcher Adding flexibility before you need it is an error in itself (IMO), but making the default value of a property mutable means you increase the probability it will vary. Any increase in the size of your state space increases the probability of errors -- which is why fields should be immutable, unless mutability is needed today.

Comment: @finleyarcher The question is, when do you need to change that value ? Is it only done at bootstrap or can it be done in the runtime. If it's only done at bootstrap, don't bother with synchronized.

Comment: @Walfrat it's currently being done at runtime.

Comment: @FrankHileman Yes gold plating or wasted time or whatever, not sure im onboard with error. 

The concern of configurable comes from the inconsistent configuration in the past. 1. the configuration changes, 2. whomever does not change it in every class, 3. things break. 

Reading a configuration from a file is less than ideal because our configuration management is changing *right* now. So the flexibility is needed atleast until that is settled. (The advantage here being no need to recompile the package containing the factories). Am i making more or less sense?

Comment: Last question : have you case where you create many Tacos at once, if so I supposed they're supposed to have the them cheese ? If so that mean that putting synchronized on method won't be enough. Unless you change the prototype to create as many Tacos needed at once in your class.

Comment: @FrankHileman In that specific case, talking about immutability is non-sense, changing either mutable object, or the reference of an immutable object where it's needed will require synchronization aniway. If it is needed in one case in will be needed in the other case. We do not know the specific requirment of OP. I'am assuming that if it is changing at runtime it is because it need to, even if I prefer it would not.

Comment: @Walfrat i think i am getting a better grasp of the underlying static issue and the synchronization issues it causes. if you see my comment dlasalle's answer i may drop the static handling of default values. i need to work this out with the guy doing our new configuration. i knew the static would work because its cheap and easy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option B seems highly preferable for a static factory, as allowing for configuration of a static class is just asking for trouble.

- In a single threaded environment you will still see issues, where module `A` configures the factory, but module `B` was expecting a different configuration. This is especially important when you do not "own" all of the client code (still important if you do though).
- In a multi-threaded environment (even if you `synchronize` the methods), you could have one thread change the default while another is trying to get the default, and end up with non-deterministic behavior (due to the race condition).

If you want a configurable factory, make it non-static. This will make the code re-usable. If it is configurable and static, no one can use it, because they can't rely on other programmers in the same code base changing the configuration else-where.

Comment: You very last section has got me thinking. The reality is no one will be calling configure at the time of or after the first object is created. But leaving the possibility is just as much a concern as the flexibility.

using option B as a base point,
if i create two constructors one with new configured values, and one empty constructor and remove static from the rest of the methods. I will still have default values, but they can only be configured by creating a separate object. Yeah?

Comment: in the above i did not mean to include removing the static methods as part of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Option A seems the closest to what I would be expecting. It looks like you have tried to implement the Builder pattern for your factory, but it doesn't seem to provide a complete interface.

I recommend reading Vitali Fedorenko's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997482/does-java-support-default-parameter-values) and then follow the option 5 from that answer.

Comment: The main problem with using a builder is for me, in this instance, I do not always own the code for "Taco" or this would be a perfect fit. I am trying to enforce a standardized configuration for all of our commonly used objects (whether we own them or not). This pattern will be used across about 20-25 objects.

Comment: I think the Builder pattern is the best choice too. If you don't own the code, create a Wrapper class for those third-party classes and implement the Builder pattern in these wrappers (and use the wrapper from now on the entire project). The pattern itself is already the one you should follow for all your classes IMO.

Comment: The builder pattern is great. For this specific situation tho, if someone wants to change the configuration, it will only pertain to that builder object. This is why I went completely static. I may be missing something so feel free to correct me. 

For a specific use case of the edited Option A: When our new configuration management is implemented and integrated, I don't want them to have to go and recompile my library. I want the configuration manager to be able to read their configuration, call my configures, and the programs will run without further changes.